# Get reference to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentmanager

**Problem:** Few code samples did not help me to get a reference to my Fragment. It always returns null.

**What I did:** I have an activity that contains a Fragment. The fragment does the networking. If it has finished loading I call `onNetworkingFinished` method in the parent activity.

Inside of the `onNetworkingFinished` method I would need to get a reference to the fragment to get the possibility to call a method of the fragment.

The fragment is for sure not null because the onNetworkingFinished method gets called by it...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaschineFragment.Callbacks{

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FloatingActionButton mFab;
    private CoordinatorLayout mCordinatorLayout;
    private MaschineFragment mMaschineFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.maschinelistcontainer, new MaschineFragment(), "maschinefragment");

        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.dual_pane)){
            ft.add(R.id.detailreviewcontainer, new ReviewMaschineFragment(), "detailfragment");
        }

        ft.commit();

        mCordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.maschineCoordinatorLayout);
        mFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_download_maschinen);
        mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkingFinished(boolean finishedWithError) {
        if(finishedWithError){
            Log.i("Networking", "Daten NUR lokal geladen");
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(mCordinatorLayout, getResources().getString(R.string.networking_finished_with_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        } else {
            Log.i("Networking", "Fertig geladen");
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(mCordinatorLayout, getResources().getString(R.string.networking_finished_with_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        }

        mMaschineFragment = (MaschineFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maschine_fragment);
        if (mMaschineFragment==null || ! mMaschineFragment.isInLayout()) {
            Log.i("Maschine Fragment", "NULL und nicht im Layout");
        }
        else {
            Log.i("Maschine Fragment", "VORHANDEN");
        }



    }

 (...)


}
```

Comment: You should use interfaces to communicate between fragment and activity

Comment: I see you attach a tag to every fragment you use, why not try `findFragmentByTag` ?

Comment: You should search for the tag "maschinefragment" instead of the ID.  The ID you pass in is the View ID, not the Fragment ID (Yeah it's confusing).

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi: I always use interfaces to pass data back from fragment to activity. But the other way round I get the issue: cyclic inheritance involing <package.name.Fragment>

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your fragment reference to your onNetworkingFinished method.

example: you have to call onNetworkingFinished method from fragment by someobject.onNetworkingFinished (boolean finishedWithError,YOURFRAGMENTNAME.this);

Implement the **onNetworkingFinished** method in activity should be

```
 @Override
    public void onNetworkingFinished(boolean finishedWithError,YOURFRAGMENTNAME obj)
 {
  //here you can have fragment access in obj
}
```

Comment: When I try to pass the reference in the fragment like this:   mCallbacks.onNetworkingFinished(false, this); I get the issue: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONArray>', required: 'com.stack.overflow.MaschineFragment

Comment: Can you please post your interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding `findFragmentById()`. The argument that this method gets is the id of the View that you previously added your fragment to, not the id of the fragment.

You added your fragment like this:

```
ft.add(R.id.maschinelistcontainer, new MaschineFragment(), "maschinefragment");
```

So you should try to get your fragment like this:

```
mMaschineFragment = (MaschineFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maschinelistcontainer);
```

Since you have specified tag, you can get it by tag too:

```
mMaschineFragment = (MaschineFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("maschinefragment");
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Unfortunately I get for all of your suggestions null. What else could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this 
**ft.add(R.id.maschinelistcontainer, new MaschineFragment(), "maschinefragment");**

try this

**mMaschineFragment = new MaschineFragment();
ft.add(R.id.maschinelistcontainer, mMaschineFragment, "maschinefragment");**

and then access it by the global object **mMaschineFragment**;

also you can call **onNetworkingFinished** function by providing refrence of the calling fragment like:

```
@Override
public void onNetworkingFinished(boolean finishedWithError, MaschineFragment fragment) {
    if(finishedWithError){
        Log.i("Networking", "Daten NUR lokal geladen");
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(mCordinatorLayout, getResources().getString(R.string.networking_finished_with_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
    } else {
        Log.i("Networking", "Fertig geladen");
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(mCordinatorLayout, getResources().getString(R.string.networking_finished_with_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
    }

    mMaschineFragment = fragment;
    if (mMaschineFragment==null || ! mMaschineFragment.isInLayout()) {
        Log.i("Maschine Fragment", "NULL und nicht im Layout");
    }
    else {
        Log.i("Maschine Fragment", "VORHANDEN");
    }



}
```